# Retrieving Java Objects from a json post request

Tags: java, json, jersey

I am developing a restful web application using java and jax-rs. In server side, I have to accept Json type requests as given by the client using POST method.

```
@POST
@Path("/Request")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String process(SMessage message) throws Exception  {
         message.getHeader();
         message.getBody();
}
```

The json object have two composite fields like in the below format.

```
{
  "header": {
    "serviceType": "A"
  },
  "body": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "abc"
  }
}
```

Based on the serviceType specified in the Header field, the parameters in the body will differ. I need to map this body field in to a java POJO class. The POJO class is not the same for all requests. How can I achieve this effectively?

Comment: Receive a String parameter in the rest method and the JSON data will be received as a String. Now depending on the type using an Object mapper  you can map it to the POJO you need,

Comment: Well, you could try to parse the json generically first (e.g. Jackson's `readTree()`), get the body subtree and then parse that into the correct POJO. However, wouldn't it make more sense to provide a service per type instead of making the distinction in the post body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Jackson` as your JSON parser, a simple way is to declare `body` to be a `JsonNode` to handle dynamic keys as follows:

```
class MyResponse {
    private MyHeader header;
    private JsonNode body;

    //general getters and setters
}
```

And I assumed that you have already a POJO for `header` such as:

```
class MyHeader {
    private String serviceType;

    //general getters and setters
}
```

Finally, let's verify that it works:

```
String responseStr = "{\"header\": {\"serviceType\": \"A\"},\"body\": {\"id\": \"1\",\"name\": \"abc\"}}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyResponse myResponse = mapper.readValue(responseStr, MyResponse.class);
System.out.println(myResponse.getBody().get("name").asText());
```

Console output:

> abc

Another way to solve this issue is by using `Map` and everything else is the same:

```
class MyResponse {
    private MyHeader header;
    private Map<String, Object> body;

    //general getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works !..However I found that the GSON library has a feature like in the ObjectMapper class you mentioned above. We can create the relevent type of object by passing the json string.